# How to Debug Selenium WebDriver Actions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I am using Selenium WebDriver and run into a issue.

In the UI, elements are seen by the WebDriver but it can't perform any actions such as click, type, select etc. Elements are found by Selenium and returned as an instance of webelement. I can get, getText(), isEnabled() etc, but it won't perform any actions. There are no exceptions, it just hangs.

I don't understand this behavior. If it seen by the WebDriver, it should click. I have tried using actions. That too shows the same behavior.

How to debug this issue? Any ideas?

Sample code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(Timeout), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
element=driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("test");
```

This works in other websites. Not in the one I'm testing. So I don't know if there is an issue in WebDriver or in the AUT.

EDIT: After moving to Selenium 2.13.0, above issues resolved. But I still want to know how to debug in case of error.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet to show us how you are using WebDriver?

Comment: The code works in other websites. Any way, I'll put the sample code

Comment: Have you got frames/iframes that you haven't switched to?

Comment: can you do it with debugging tool as used with a normal  java program?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to debug the code is to write a wrapper around `WebDriverEventListener` and listen to the logs. Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: Here's possible implementation and how to hook the listener into a driver: http://simon-reekie.me/twist-experiences/logging-selenium-2-events-in-twist/